# Websocket client in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, websocket

I see lots of libraries and examples for writing websockets **servers** in Haskell, but what about clients?  Are there any libraries around for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The websockets package supports client-side applications

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.7.0.0/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html#g:12

See the example:

https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/client.hs

Comment: It seems it doesn't support `wss://`  :(

Comment: @singpolyma, [wuss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wuss-1.1.4) wraps the [websockets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets) package with TLS to support `wss://`

Answer (score 2):

The [`websockets`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.7.3.0) package contains a [websocket client](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.7.3.0/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html#g:12) as well. After initiating the connection with `connect`, you write the client code just like you would for the server, using the [`WebSockets`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.7.3.0/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html#t%3aWebSockets) monad.